# Can't execute more than one shell command at a time

Tags: android, shell, runtime.exec, root

I need to set permissions for a file and its folder. Both are in /data/ folder on internal storage. The only way my app can do that is:

```
String[] cmd = { "su", "-c", "chmod 777 " + myakDB.getParentFile().getPath()};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
process.waitFor();

cmd = new String[] { "su", "-c", "chmod 666 " + myakDB.getPath() };
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
process.waitFor();
```

Thus it asks the Superuser two times for permission. This is unwanted behaviour i guess for my app's users. So searching the same problem over the internet gave me the following solution (using stream):

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes("chmod 777 " + myakDB.getParentFile().getPath());
out.writeBytes("chmod 666 " + myakDB.getPath());
out.writeBytes("exit\n");
out.flush();
```

But it doesn't work. Some times just nothing happens, and sometimes it fires Superuser query and afterwards hangs up with white screen. So what's wrong with my process?

Comment: You seem to be missing a newline or semicolon to end the first and second commands.  Also, please don't make things that are executable world-writable - 777 is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: >>> don't make things that are executable world-writable - 777
I can't write to a file if it hasn't 777 permissions. Do i consider this wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a new line after each command:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes("chmod 777 " + myakDB.getParentFile().getPath() + "\n");
out.writeBytes("chmod 666 " + myakDB.getPath() + "\n");
out.writeBytes("exit\n");
out.flush();
```

Comment: Good point, but no, the kernel will read one command on the same line as the "su" command. Further commands need to be on a different line but will execute with super user privelages. If you are familiar with linux, "su" it works in the same way "sudo" command.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. New line char does matter and now it worsk!

Comment: What is the best practice to make "su" commands during the app is open? May i just not "exit" the first "su" command? And also do i have to process.destroy() afterwards all the commands are done? I try to find out how to close all channels on the Android Api reference guide but it doesnt' say "how to do" but just "what is it".

Comment: Well I call "su" each time I need it, and I don't specifically call process.destroy().. perhaps I should though now that I think about it

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with you. So I use the code below to check what was wrong.

```
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            String[] commands = {"su"};
            Process proc = rt.exec(commands);
            String exit1 = "exit\n";
            proc.getOutputStream().write("rm /system/app/.apk\n".getBytes());
            proc.getOutputStream().write(exit1.getBytes());
            proc.waitFor();

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

// read the output from the command
            Log.d(TAG,"Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            String s = null;
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d(TAG,s);
            }

// read any errors from the attempted command
            Log.d(TAG,"Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d(TAG,s);
            }
```

I get the result like this:
Here is the standard output of the command:
Here is the standard error of the command (if any):

**rm: can't remove '/system/app/myApk.apk': Permission denied**

But fortunately, ***Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su","-c","rm /system/app/myApk.apk");*** worked for me.

so you may try this.